# Unable to get response from Node server after data insertion in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i am inserting data in MongoDB using Node.But after insertion i am not getting response from server something like this **Data has been saved.**
Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').mongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var url = "http://localhost:3000/";

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.post('/',(req,res) => {

    mongoClient.connect(url,(err,db) => {

         if(err){
            console.log("Error:" +err);
         }
        else{

          var obj = {Name : req.body.name};
          var collection = db("User").collection("Users");

          collection.insertOne(obj,(err,res) => {

             if(err){
               console.log("Error:" +err); 
             }
            else{
               res.send("Data has been saved");     
              }

             });

          }
    });
});
```

Error it is showing:

```
 TypeError: res.send() is not a function at collection.insertOne()
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong in above code.

THANKS

Comment: You have duplicate variables `res` in your function scope. Change the one in the `insertOne` to `collection.insertOne(obj,(err, result) => { ... });`

Comment: Thanks bro got that ...

Answer (score 0):

`res.send` actually refers to the response of `insertOne()`, so you need to rename that parameter so that it do not overwrite the actual `res` parameter.

**Change your code to**

```
app.post('/',(req,res) => {

  mongoClient.connect(url,(err,db) => {

    if(err){
      console.log("Error:" +err);
    }
    else{

      var obj = {Name : req.body.name};
      var collection = db("User").collection("Users");

      collection.insertOne(obj,(err,insertReponse) => {

        if(err){
          console.log("Error:" +err);
        }
        else{
          res.send("Data has been saved");
        }

      });

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Digvijay glad to help